# Dimensionality of fluid flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism, kinematics, computational-physics, spacetime-dimensions

In some textbooks flow is classified as one, two, or three-dimensional depending on the number of
space coordinates (i.e. x,y,z) required to specify the velocity field while according to some other textbooks it depends on how many components of the velocity field are non zero (i.e. u.v,w as per cartesian coordinates) and also on space coordinates i.e. for 1D flow u=f(x,t) & v=w=0 , for 2D flow u=f(x,y,t) v=f(x,y,t) and w=0, for 3D flow u=f(x,y,z,t) v=f(x,y,z,t) w=f(x,y,z,t).

If I consider a velocity field $\vec{V}$ = (x+y) $\hat i$ + (x-y) $\hat j$ + 2 $\hat k$ ( valid velocity field because satisfying continuity ,considering incompressible flow), then it is 2D as per first approach (because velocity field depends on x and y only) but as per second approach it is 3D.

or If I have a velocity field $\vec{V}$ = (x+y) $\hat i$ + (x-y+z) $\hat j$  (again this is a valid velocity field because it satisfies continuity equation, considering incompressible flow) then according to first approach it is a 3D flow because velocity field depends on x,y and z. But as per second approach I can't decide because it has two components u and v but v is a function of x,y and z. Then is it a 2D or 3D flow.
So what is the criteria to classify flow as 1D, 2D or 3D ?

Comment: I'm not going to attempt a complete answer, but I don't like either of your definitions. For example the flow through a long pipe that is coiled into a helix can usually be considered 1-dimensional.

Comment: These are the definitions as per textbook, first one is as per Fluid Mechanics by Fox and McDonald and the second one is as per Fluid mechanics by Cengel. I am confused between these two descriptions of same concept.

Comment: I agree with the first definition you gave.  In the first example you gave, as reckoned by an observer traveling with a velocity of 2 in the z direction, there would be no velocity component in z (and he would perceive a 2D flow).  That's why the second definition is silly.

Comment: Yes with reference to an observer traveling in z direction, it can be considered as a 2D flow. But as per a fixed frame of reference if we consider pathline of a particle then it should be a 3D analysis.

Comment: If I consider second example then the velocity vector lies in a plane but as z coordinate changes then flow patterns will vary in z direction then it should also be considered as a 3D flow. Is this approach correct ?